# Perform case sensitive search in NiFi search box?

Tags: apache-nifi

Does NiFi support Case-Sensitive searching within its search box?

I'm not talking about creating a search function in a processor. I'm trying to find exact matches within our NiFi flows.

e.g.

I am looking for exact match of 'fileName' NOT 'filename'.

Is this supported in NiFi (newer versions)?